# Need to make a css grid column narrower that the other ones?

Tags: css, width

How do I make a css grid column narrower than the others?
This column is set to fill the entire left side of my page and I tried to narrow it  with `width: 10%` and it does get narrower, however there is still a blank space left between the now-narrowed column and the next one, that would be filled by the column if I would set `width: 100%`.
My question is: How do I get rid of this space? 
Same goes for rows.

```
.bodycontainer {
display: grid;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
grid-column-gap: 0px;
grid-row-gap: 0px;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
margin-top: 1.5%;}

.container1 {
height: 100%;
grid-row-start:1;
grid-row-end:3;
width:30%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);}

.container2 {
background-color: blue;
grid-column-start: 2;
grid-column-end: 5;
width: 100%;
height: 20%;}
```

.container1 is supposed to  be the sidebar

Comment: can you update the question with your code?

Comment: I just added the code, thanks

Comment: Whenever you are adding code, please make sure that it is sufficient to reproduce the issue being tackled.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved it.
Apparently the problem was that `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;` from body container. Changed it to `grid-template-columns: 100px 30% 20%;` and it seems that I can play at will with these dimensions.